# How to get event for mailgun when attachment get download or click?

Tags: salesforce, apex, mailgun

I am trying to get the event for mailgun, that attachment is downloaded or else click on that, but i didn't see anything in event of mailgun.

Can you please help me.

Comment: You should provide more info about your problem

Comment: i write a code for mailgun to salesforce apex integration.with the help of that i am able to send mail with attachment.Now i am tracking the event that is happening in that.so now i want the event from mailgun that attachment is get download or user click on attachment??